# tc filter does not apply between a virtual interface and a physical one

Tags: linux, tc

I am working on a project aiming at managing a network between several components. For project purpose, we want to test some bad network effects using netem. The used commands are the following ones:

```
$ tc qdisc add dev virtualif1 root handle 1: htb
$ tc class add dev virtualif1 parent 1: classid 1:10 htb rate 10gbit
$ tc qdisc add dev virtualif1 parent 1:10 handle 20: netem delay 5000ms
```

The catch is: I'm new on the project and on linux network management and I have to understand and fix the problems... So, as I understand it, this creates some sort of rules that can be applied or not.

Now, we apply it using:

`$ tc filter add dev virtualif1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 127.78.0.25/32 match ip dst 127.78.0.98/32 flowid 1:13`

My problem is when the ip 127.78.0.98 refers to a virtual interface, the delay is of five seconds as intended but when it refers to a physical interface, nothing happens and no delay is applied. I have tested the other way (from physical interface to virtual one and adapting the tc class and tc qdisc commands) and no delay is applied either.

We are working on virtual machine with Centos 7.7.1908.

I have done some research with my few knowledge in this field but I can't understand what is the problem here. So all advice on this are welcommed.